# How do I prevent 'Open with...' showing multiples of same app?

Tags: macos, finder

Anyone know why this happens and how to make it show only one instance of each?

[image: Multiple instances]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, I was able to resolve this using the following command:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`